# Why does a TF data source not update, when its inputs are changed?

Tags: terraform

I have, roughly, the following:

```
variable "my_users" {
    "alice@example.com",
    "bob@example.com",
    "chloe@example.com",
}

data "azuread_user" "my_users" {
  for_each = toset(var.my_users)
  user_principal_name = each.key
}

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "my_users" {
  for_each = data.azuread_user.my_users

  scope = <a scope>
  role_definition_name = "<a role def>"
  principal_id = each.value.id
}
```

Out of band, we removed the `azurerm_role_assignment` for Bob. Oops. But it is "fine", since Bob left & we're deprovisioning him anyways. I remove `bob@example.com` from the `var.my_users`, & run `terraform plan`. However, I get:

```
# azurerm_role_assignment.my_users["bob@example.com"] will be created
+ resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "my_users" {
    + id                               = (known after apply)
    + name                             = (known after apply)
    + principal_id                     = "<id>"
    + principal_type                   = (known after apply)
    + role_definition_id               = (known after apply)
    + role_definition_name             = "Contributor"
    + scope                            = "/subscriptions/<id>"
    + skip_service_principal_aad_check = (known after apply)
  }
```

Why? Why are we trying to *create* Bob's role assignment, when he's not even present in the `*.tf` source anymore?

I thought at first our out-of-band removal of the role assignment was the cause (though that didn't make sense to me, fully) so I removed the role assignment from the state, using `terraform state rm 'azurerm_role_assignment.my_users["bob@example.com"]'`. That succeeded, but didn't change the plan: we're still adding Bob.

I did some digging, and apparently the state file contains `data` objects too. (That is news to me!) `bob@example.com` is present as part of that state. So it seems like `terraform plan` is using the state file's value for `data.my_users`, and since the role assignment was removed, if you use the value in the state file, then yeah, the logical operation is to add the role assignment. But what I don't get is why the value in the state file is being used: the source of a variable from which the `data` object is computed *changed*, so why is TF not saying "hey, we should refresh this `data` & oh, nothing needs to be done *empty plan*"?

(I presume I can — and perhaps need to — fix this by doing a `terraform state rm` on the actual `data` object. But I'd like to understand why I need to do that.)

In case it matters: we're on `v0.14.2` of Terraform.

Comment: Unfortunately I think this is a behavior where it matters which version of Terraform you are using, because recent versions of Terraform changed the handling of data resources to be more consistent with managed resources. Therefore I think it'd help to state which version of Terraform you are using in order to properly answer the "why" of this question.

Comment: Ah; we're on `v0.14.2`

Comment: Hmm, interesting! That's new enough to have the new behavior, so I think something weird is happening here but I can't guess what. If you can share the _entire_ output from `terraform plan` in your question (including any preparations steps like "Refreshing..." before hand), rather than just the one planned action, something else in the output might give a clue, but otherwise I'm not sure what to say.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is Bob still in your Azure Active Directory?
2. Is "bob@example.com" still being provided in `var.my_users`?
3. If you review the TF output, do you see anything along the lines of `data.azuread_user.my_users: Refreshing state...`?

Data sources are supposed to refresh on every plan, you're correct. My understanding is that the reason the results are kept in the state is so that `terraform plan` will still work if you use the `-refresh=false` flag.

You said you removed Bob's role assignment out-of-band, but you didn't say that you removed Bob (the user itself) out-of-band. Also, your code shows that you're still providing Bob's email in your `my_users` variable.

Keep in mind that the `azuread_user` data source will still find a deactivated user; the response will just have the `account_enabled` attribute set to `false`.

If "bob@example.com" is still in the `my_users` input variable, then it makes perfect sense that it's trying to re-create the role assignment: you're still providing his email in the input variable, so the data source is still trying to find him, and since his account is likely deactivated (not deleted), it's succeeding in finding him, and since you've deleted the role assignment, it's trying to re-create it.

If you're providing Bob's email in the input variable, but he's *not* in Active Directory (actually deleted, not just deactivated), then `terraform plan` should fail with an error since the `azuread_user` data source wouldn't be able to find him.

If you're not providing his email in the input variable, but it's still trying to create the role assignment, then something is seriously messed up.

My bet is that it's trying to create a role assignment for a deactivated user.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform keeps a state file in `.terraform/terraform.tfstate`, **even if your state is remote**. We had a project that often switched between terraform states through symlinking of folders. You *must* make sure that you run `terraform init  -reconfigure` every time you switch or it will reference the old project's state. Or, you can try deleting the `terraform.tfstate` file that references the old projects state.